# Opening a binary output file stream without truncation

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I am trying to open a binary output file to which I need to append some data. I cannot output the data sequentially, so I need to be able to seek within the file stream and cannot use the `std::ios::app` flag.

Unfortunately, when opening an output file stream without the `std::ios::app` flag, the file gets truncated when it is opened. Here's some sample code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

int main() {
    std::ofstream file("output.bin", std::ios::binary | std::ios::ate);

    std::streamoff orig_offset = file.tellp();
    std::cout << "Offset after opening: " << orig_offset << std::endl;

    file.seekp(0, std::ios::end);
    std::streamoff end_offset = file.tellp();
    std::cout << "Offset at end: " << end_offset << std::endl;

    file << "Hello World" << std::endl;

    std::streamoff final_offset = file.tellp();
    std::cout << "Offset after writing: " << final_offset << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I would expect every execution to append "Hello World" to the file. However, the file is truncated as soon as it is opened.

What am I doing wrong? If this is a bug in Visual Studio, are there any workarounds?

Edit:
Every time the program runs, regardless of whether the file exists or already has contents, the program outputs this:

```
Offset after opening: 0
Offset at end: 0
Offset after writing: 12
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to open the file in both output **and** input mode:

```
std::fstream file("output.bin", std::ios::in | std::ios::out | std::ios::binary | std::ios::ate);
```

Comment: Thanks, that does indeed work! Is this a bug in visual studio, or is this intended behavior from the standard? I haven't found anything documenting this...

Comment: @zennehoy Opening a file in `out` mode is equivalent to `fopen(filename, "w")`, and `fopen` call with `"w"` mode is specified to truncate the file. See e.g. [this link](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_filebuf/open) to see a list of the C++ modes and their corresponding `fopen` modes.